# Unable to disable shell_exec in php.ini

Tags: php, apache2, plesk

I've been busy all evening and morning trying to disable `shell_exec` (and some other functions) through `php.ini`, but nothing seems to work. If I run `phpinfo()`, the local value states the functions are disabled and the master value is not set.

However, if I try to run the function (function like `shell_exec()`), it still works, giving me the output, instead of being disabled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, we are completely lost. Running Ubuntu with Plesk 11.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this (and NOT running Plesk). I have this in my PHP-FPM php.ini file:

```
[HOST=mycustomer.com]
upload_max_filesize=7M
disable_functions=phpinfo,exec,shell_exec,system,passthru
```

And a script consisting

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
```

works (though it should not!) and actually shows:

```
upload_max_filesize 7M
...
disable_functions   phpinfo,exec,shell_exec,system,passthru
```

So something weird is going on. The correct file and the section are loaded (I can see that from the phpinfo output) but the settings have no effect, not the disable_functions, at least.

Looks like a bug of some sort to me.

Answer (score 0):

Service Plans > your plan > PHP settings > write "disable_functions=shell_exec" in textbox "Additional configuration directives" - click on Update & Sync

All not locked subscription get this directive in their php.ini files.

I have checked that disable_function doesn't works until it applied to "local value" and "master value". When PHP works as Apache module disable_function doesn't applied to master part. I'm sure it's happens because in apache mudule there is "Loaded Configuration File" which located in /etc/apache/ or /etc/httpd/.
So, PHP settings is merged from two separate php.ini files - from global and from subscription's php.ini.

In FastCGI mode "Loaded Configuration File" is a subscription level php.ini, so there is only one php.ini is effective.

So, you following steps is obvious:
- use FastCGI and forbid to change this mode for your users(There is such ability in plesk)
or 
- for Apache module add same directive to global php.ini

Comment: We changed that a few times, the phpinfo show the disable function but where are still able to use the shell_exec.

Comment: In the same place where you check shell_exec, check which php.ini is used. Which PHP handler is used on subscription? Apache module? FastCGI? Try to change PHP handler to FastCGI.